# Querying database inside of PHP class?

Tags: php, database, class, oop

so this is very simple.

Essentially, I'd like to connect the following class:

```
class mailManager{

function add($address){
    $check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mail_list WHERE email = '$address'");
    $exist = mysqli_num_rows($check);
    if($exist > 0){
        return "Whoops! Your email is already registered with us.";
    }else{
        if($insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO mail_list (email, datetime) VALUES ('$address', DATE)")){
            return "Success! You've joined the CSGO Earn family.";
        } else {
            return "Aw snap! There was a database communication error. Please try later.";
        }

    }

}

}
```

to the database.

However, nothing 'obvious' that I try seems to work and a google search has yielded no results that I can understand. Perhaps somebody could explain it simply for me?

Note: The SQL is there, but it doesn't do anything (obviously).

Regards

Comment: Where is `$db` defined? If it is not defined within the function, or passed as a function argument, you will not be able to use it.

Comment: First of all your db is not define. and second $exist = mysqli_num_rows($check); for this you need to change it $exist = $check->num_rows();

Comment: Try changing DATE by `NOW()`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class does not have immediate access to your `$db`.  You can do this a few different ways.

**1)** Pass `$db` into your `public function __construct($db)` and assign it to a class member like `private $db;`  *(most useful)*

You then access it like `$check = $this->db->query("..etc..");`

**2)** Pass it in via a parameter to the `add()` function like so:

```
public function add($address, $db) {
}
```

**3)** Bring it in as a global variable: *(easiest)*

```
function add($address){
    global $db;
    $check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mail_list WHERE email = '$address'");
    /*

        etc....

    */
}
```

I'd recommend learning how to do the first one as it will come in very handy when you have a number of database calls within your class.

Two more things regarding your code in the function.

1) You should use `NOW()` instead of `DATE`.

2) Since you are using the OOP implementation of mysqli, you should change `mysqli_num_rows($check);` to `$check->num_rows();`.  I'm not sure if it will work the way you have it, but even if it does it's good practice to treat your objects uniformly.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer & the extra tips at the end. I'm new to OOP if you haven't noticed.